# VBA copy and paste data from page 1 with Command Button to a specified range on page 2

Tags: excel, vba

I would like copy and paste certain cells in a line based on a value in one cell (can be any value, the criteria is that cell is not empty) into a specific range on a second spreadsheet.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
a = Worksheets("Formulary").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Worksheets("Billing Sheet").Range("A13")


For i = 2 To a

    If Worksheets("Formulary").Cells(i, 4).Value <> "" Then
     'Change # to be the number column of Item Number
         Worksheets("Formulary").Cells(i, 1).Copy
'Change ,# to be the number column of where you want it pasted.
        Worksheets("Formulary").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Billing Sheet").Range(b + 1, 1)
'Change ,# to be the number column of product name
        Worksheets("Formulary").Cells(i, 2).Copy
'Change ,# to be the number column of where you want it pasted.
        Worksheets("Formulary").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Billing Sheet").Range(b + 1, 2)
'Change ,# to be the number column of Quantity
        Worksheets("Formulary").Cells(i, 4).Copy
'Change ,# to be the number column of where you want it pasted.
        Worksheets("Formulary").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Billing Sheet").Range(b + 1, 3)
'Change ,# to be the number column of UOM
        Worksheets("Formulary").Cells(i, 5).Copy
'Change ,# to be the number column of where you want it pasted.
        Worksheets("Formulary").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Billing Sheet").Range(b + 1, 4)
'Change # to be the number column of Supply Type
        Worksheets("Formulary").Cells(i, 8).Copy
'Change ,# to be the number column of where you want it pasted.
        Worksheets("Formulary").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Billing Sheet").Range(b + 1, 5)

    End If
Next
Application.CutCopyMode = False

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Formulary").Cells(1, 1).Select


End Sub
```

Here is the situation: I have two pages, Formulary and Billing Sheet. The quantity will be entered into Column D on Formulary. After all of the lines with a needed quantity have been entered, the Command Button (ActiveX Controls) will be clicked, transposing Column A, B, D, E, and H (based on if Column D has a quantity entered in any given line) from Formulary into range A13:G29 on the Billing Sheet.

It is just returning with an error every time. In my code example I have written out each execution line I am trying to get because that is what I found online. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is `b`? And what line throws the error?

Comment: Slightly confused: are you actually transposing the data, or just copying and pasting the data without any transformation done to that data?

Comment: Good point, I am just trying to copy and paste the data... not really transpose anything. I adjusted the phrasing.

Comment: BigBen;
b was intended to be the range, so it would start pasting at A13 and then the +1 should return it to the next available open line. 
 It shows the error: 
Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object defined error" 
In line:
"Worksheets("Formulary").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Billing Sheet").Range(b + 1, 1)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBA does not like how you are referencing the cells. For Range, you need the column letter and a number in quotation marks. The way that you are referencing your cells is using the Cells notation. Also, you need to start the reference point for b, otherwise VBA does not know where to start.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
a = Worksheets("Formulary").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
'Dim rng As Range
'Set rng = Worksheets("Billing Sheet").Range("A13")
b = 13

For i = 2 To a

    If Worksheets("Formulary").Cells(i, 4).Value <> "" Then
     'Change # to be the number column of Item Number
         Worksheets("Formulary").Cells(i, 1).Copy
'Change ,# to be the number column of where you want it pasted.
        Worksheets("Billing Sheet").Cells(b + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
'Change ,# to be the number column of product name
        Worksheets("Formulary").Cells(i, 2).Copy
'Change ,# to be the number column of where you want it pasted.
        Worksheets("Formulary").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Billing Sheet").Cells(b + 1, 2)
'Change ,# to be the number column of Quantity
        Worksheets("Formulary").Cells(i, 4).Copy
'Change ,# to be the number column of where you want it pasted.
        Worksheets("Formulary").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Billing Sheet").Cells(b + 1, 3)
'Change ,# to be the number column of UOM
        Worksheets("Formulary").Cells(i, 5).Copy
'Change ,# to be the number column of where you want it pasted.
        Worksheets("Formulary").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Billing Sheet").Cells(b + 1, 4)
'Change # to be the number column of Supply Type
        Worksheets("Formulary").Cells(i, 8).Copy
'Change ,# to be the number column of where you want it pasted.
        Worksheets("Formulary").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Billing Sheet").Cells(b + 1, 5)
        b = b + 1
    End If
Next
Application.CutCopyMode = False

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Formulary").Cells(1, 1).Select


End Sub
```

I commented out where you declared rng because it didn't seem to be used in this code.

Comment: You are amazing! I see what you mean about the errors that I made. Thank you very much!